# Silverlight XAML Binding -- Decimal to Double

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, xaml, converters, numeric-conversion

I've got some Columns in a DataGridView that have their Binding property set to something like the following:

```
Binding="{Binding NetPrice}"
```

The problem is that this NetPrice field is a Decimal type and I would like to convert it to Double inside the DataGrid.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: That doesn't work as-is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a Converter.  A converter takes one variable and "converts" it to another.

There are a [lot](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/jesseliberty/archive/2008/10/12/data-binding-data-conversion.aspx) of [resources](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx) for creating converters.  They are also easy to implement in c# and use in xaml.

Your converter could look similar to this:

```
public class DecimalToDoubleConverter : IValueConverter   
{   
    public object Convert( 
        object value,   
        Type targetType,   
        object parameter,   
        CultureInfo culture)   
    {   
        decimal visibility = (decimal)value;
        return (double)visibility;
    }   

    public object ConvertBack(   
        object value,   
        Type targetType,   
        object parameter,   
        CultureInfo culture)   
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("I'm really not here"); 
    }   
}
```

Once you've created your converter, you will need to tell your xaml file to include it like this:

in your namespaces (at the very top of your xaml), include it like so:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ClassLibraryName;assembly=ClassLibraryName"
```

Then declare a static resource, like so:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <converters:DecimalToDoubleConverter x:Key="DecimalToDoubleConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

Then add it to your binding like this:

```
Binding ="{Binding Path=NetPrice, Converter={StaticResource DecimalToDoubleConverter}"
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used Converters before, I just thought that maybe there was an alternative with some of the simpler data types.